# Is there a proper title for a woman betrothed to a king?

Tags: 18th-century

Does the title of a princess change when she is betrothed to a king?  If she were in line for the throne of England and was betrothed to the king of France, how would the French court refer to her?
Thanks

Comment: Depends on the country.  I doubt that betrothal grants a title in any country.  In France Salic law prohibits inheritance through the female lime, so the question is moot.

Comment: The "Be Nice" rule prevents me from answering how the ladies of the French court would most likely refer to her. 8^0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the British monarchy, the answer seems to be "no". Since the Act of Union in 1707, only two monarchs have married while on the throne, George III and Victoria. Both of their spouses were royal, and neither had any special title during the engagement.

George III married Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz, in part because she had no experience of politics. The engagement was formalised on 15th August 1761, and they were married on 8th September; there would hardly have been any point in giving her a special title for three weeks.

Victoria proposed to Albert on 15th October 1839, and they were married on 10th February 1840. He had no special title or style during the engagement, although he was made a Knight of the Garter in December 1839.

It's not clear just when Edward VIII proposed to Wallis Simpson, but he made it officially known on 16th November 1936, and abdicated on 10th December. She was not a princess, and certainly had no title until she actually married him, when she became the Duchess of Windsor.

Men who marry daughters of a British monarch sometimes receive a peerage, bestowed on them the morning before the wedding. However, they have no special title before then. Examples include Prince Phillip, who was made Duke of Edinburgh on the morning of his marriage to Princess Elizabeth, and Antony Armstrong-Jones, who was made Earl of Snowdon on the morning of his marriage to Princess Margret. Mark Phillips did not receive a peerage when he married Princess Anne; he may have declined it.

Comment: Prince Philip was not a commoner, he was  Prince Philip of Greece and Denmark.

Comment: Changed. I'd misremembered the status of the Greek monarchy: it was extant at the time.

Comment: Prince Philip had renounced his Greek titles and become a British subject before his engagement to Princess Elizabeth was announced, so theoretically he was not royal. And, AFAIK, Princess Anne and Mark Philips refused a title on their marriage.